# how to check that the numbers of an array are consecutive and print the missing number so that they are consecutive? PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

this is the problem that I have to solve:

Given an array of elements, finding the first and least missing positive element, the array can have duplicate numbers and negative numbers. The result must be printed on the screen
Examples
[-1,9, 0, 8] should print: 1
[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,5,6,3,13,4,6,5, -1, -2] should print: 7

this is my code:

```
$numeros = array(1, 3, 6, 4);
sort($numeros);
$contador = 1;
foreach ($numeros as $numero)
{
  $numero1 - 1;
  if($contador != 1 && $numero1 = $numero-1)
  {
    $resultado[] = $numero+1;
    echo $resultado[0];
    break;
  }

$i++;
$contador++;

}
```

The problem is that the second value is omit for the "if" with the condition: "$contador != 1".
In this code, prints 3, but it would have to print -2 because is sort (-3, 1, 2, 4) and the first case where the numbers are not consecutives is in "-3,1" case.

Note: I found an error, is not sorting the array :'(

Answer (score 1):

This function will give you the results you want. First it generates all the unique, positive values (since you ask for only the lowest missing *positive* number) using `array_filter` to strip negative numbers, followed by `array_unique`. Then it loops over the remaining elements, looking for one which is not equal to the previous element + 1. If all the elements are consecutive, it returns false.

```
function find_missing($numeros) {
    $numeros = array_filter(array_unique($numeros), function ($v) { return $v >= 0; });
    sort($numeros);
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($numeros); $i++) {
        if ($numeros[$i] != $numeros[$i-1] + 1) {
            return $numeros[$i-1] + 1;
        }
    }
    // all numbers consecutive
    return false;
}
```

You can call it like so:

```
$m = find_missing(array(1, 3, 6, 4));
echo ($m === false) ? "array is consecutive\n" : "$m is the first missing number\n";
$m = find_missing(array(-1,9, 0, 8));
echo ($m === false) ? "array is consecutive\n" : "$m is the first missing number\n";
$m = find_missing(array(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,5,6,3,13,4,6,5, -1, -2));
echo ($m === false) ? "array is consecutive\n" : "$m is the first missing number\n";
```

Output:

```
2 is the first missing number 
1 is the first missing number 
7 is the first missing number
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/9Qfpp)

Answer (score 1):

At first you can select only the unique values. Then you sort it. If there is redundant data it will be effective. Now simply run a loop. Define a check variable as the smallest positive integer. At first if the number is less than zero continue it. If the check is in the array then continue and increment the check. Otherwise print it and break the loop.

```
<?php
$numeros = array(1, 3, 6, 4);
$newArray = array_unique($numeros);
sort($newArray);
$check = 1;
foreach($newArray as $new){
    if($new<=0){
        continue;
    }
    if(in_array($check,$newArray)){
        $check++;
        continue;
    }else{
        echo $check;
        break;
    }
}
?>
```